# one of the webfront ends not responding Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I have setup sharepoint farm with 2 webfront ends everything was working fine but now when i m trying to deploy any solution its not getting deployed to one WFE,My solution is getting stuck on deploying status message and when I kill the timer job associated with it ...its showing that it gets deployed on 1 but not on other...

what are the things I can check for this?

Comment: @TTL: please look at your server and sharepoint logs and let us know what errors are being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You should try resetting the OWSTimer.exe Service (Windows SharePoint Service Timer).  Then do the push.